# How to keep users viewport scrolled to the right after a component is rerendered in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, mudblazor

Here's the Mudblazor 'pen' containing the default code provided from the MudBlazor dropzone docs with a few changes. Namely a JavaScript call for when the viewport expands on the x axis. I want to keep the add column box focused in the viewport.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcdYSuLarxRtppw

I've had to comment out the scrolltoRightmost(); call as I can't include the `<script>` call inside the 'pen' for demo purposes.

When a new column is added during `OnValidSectionSubmit`, I call `await ScrollToRightmost();`

```
private async void OnValidSectionSubmit(EditContext context)
{
    _sections.Add(new KanBanSections(newSectionModel.Name, false, String.Empty));
    newSectionModel.Name = string.Empty;
    _addSectionOpen = false;
    await ScrollToRightmost();
}
```

ScrollToRightmost invokes my JavaScript call.

```
private async Task ScrollToRightmost()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToRightmost", "kanban-container");
    }
```

Here is the JavaScript for the call to scroll the viewport right to its max-width.

```
function scrollToRightmost(containerId) {
    console.log("scrollToRightmost called with container ID:", containerId);
    const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    if (container) {
        console.log("container found:", container);
        container.scrollLeft = container.scrollWidth;
    } else {
        console.log("container not found");
    }
}
```

The current implementation performs poorly, it fails to scroll the entire viewport width. It is probable that an aberrant Blazor lifecycle event is causing this anomaly, such as a delay in updating the DOM. Still, I'm not certain!

Comment: Try changing `async void OnValidSectionSubmit` to `async Task OnValidSectionSubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay before the js function is invoked.

I'm not sure what causes this but adding the delay seems to do the trick.
It seems like the component rerendering finishes right in the middle of the DOM event.

```
private async Task ScrollToRightmost()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToRightmost", "kanban-container");
}
```